# "Show all content" message

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online

I just added a page viewer web part to my site page and entered the link to the URL I want displayed. Now, every time I go to that site page this message pops up on the bottom of my web browser  [image]

The page viewer web part won't display until I click on "Show all content". If you don't click on it fast enough, the message disappears and you have to refresh the page to see it again.

Comment: that is expected if you are linking to http content on a https site like sharepoint online

Comment: Did you try adding your url as a trusted site?

Comment: Explain how to add as a trusted site please.

Comment: Internet Options -> Security tab -> trusted sites.
Bellow you will see a button "Sites", click on it and add the url of your site in the displayed window

Answer (score 1):

Your site is most likely accessed via HTTPS:// , correct?
If so, all links that display content on your site also need to be HTTPS.

So, if you site is:  https://example.com
...and you attempt to load content from a different site (using a page viewer web part in your case) it ALSO needs to have the HTTPS:// protocol.
So instead of this:

**http:**//google.com

do this:

**https:**//google.com

..to access your external content.

Comment: Correct. It is https://. I will give this a try.

Comment: If this answer helped you, could you please mark it as the answer?  Thanks